# How use some options for an enumitem list inside a proof environment?

Tags: enumitem

The following source explains and illustrates the problem: how to modify `propertylist` so as to allow it to use the option `[labelindent=0pt]` at the list's beginning and the `[resume]` option when resuming the list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{proplis}{enumerate}{1}
\newenvironment{propertylist}[1]{%
  \setlist[proplis,1]{%
  wide,leftmargin=*,label=\upshape(#1\arabic*)}\begin{proplis}%
  \upshape}
  {\end{proplis}}

\newcommand*{\textsfdot}[1]{\textsf{#1.}}
\newlist{pfpartsperiod}{description}{1}
\setlist[pfpartsperiod,1]{%
  font=\normalfont,
  itemindent=0pt,
  wide,
  itemsep=0pt,topsep=2pt,
  format={\normalfont\textsfdot}
}
\begin{document}

This is how \verb!propertylist! works:
\begin{propertylist}{P}
\item Property one.
\item Property two.
\end{propertylist}

Options \verb!labelindent=0pt! and \verb!resume! for an \verb!enumitem! lists prevents extra space after ``\emph{Proof.} '' as in:
\begin{proof}
%
\begin{pfpartsperiod}[labelindent=0pt]
\item[Sufficiency] The condition suffices because of thi.
\end{pfpartsperiod}
\begin{pfpartsperiod}[resume]
\item[Necessity] The condition is also necessary since that.
\end{pfpartsperiod}
%
\end{proof}
%
\noindent\textbf{How can these options be used}, instead, with \verb!propertylist!, as in the following?
\begin{proof}
%
\begin{propertylist}{P}[labelindent=0pt]
\item Property one.
\end{propertylist}
\begin{propertylist}{P}[resume]
\item Property two.
\end{propertylist}
%
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image: How modify propertylist to allow same options as pfpartperiod]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd like that `\begin{propertylist}{P}` is able to pass an argument in brackets to `proplis`, but this can only be done if `\begin{proplis}` is the *last* item in the definition. You have `\upshape` there, instead.

But you actually have to use the “internal” form `\proplis` in order for `resume` to work, because otherwise it cannot process the right environment name to resume from.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{proplis}{enumerate}{1}
\newenvironment{propertylist}[1]{%
  \setlist[proplis,1]{%
    wide,
    leftmargin=*,
    label=\upshape(#1\arabic*),
  }%
  \upshape
  \proplis}
  {\endproplis}

\newcommand*{\textsfdot}[1]{\textsf{#1.}}
\newlist{pfpartsperiod}{description}{1}
\setlist[pfpartsperiod,1]{%
  font=\normalfont,
  itemindent=0pt,
  wide,
  itemsep=0pt,topsep=2pt,
  format={\normalfont\textsfdot}
}
\begin{document}

This is how \verb!propertylist! works:
\begin{propertylist}{P}
\item Property one.
\item Property two.
\end{propertylist}

Options \verb!labelindent=0pt! and \verb!resume! for an \verb!enumitem! 
lists prevents extra space after ``\emph{Proof.} '' as in:
\begin{proof}
%
\begin{pfpartsperiod}[labelindent=0pt]
\item[Sufficiency] The condition suffices because of thi.
\end{pfpartsperiod}
\begin{pfpartsperiod}[resume]
\item[Necessity] The condition is also necessary since that.\qedhere
\end{pfpartsperiod}
%
\end{proof}
%
\noindent\textbf{How can these options be used}, instead, with 
\verb!propertylist!, as in the following?
\begin{proof}
%
\begin{propertylist}{P}[labelindent=0pt]
\item Property one.
\end{propertylist}
\begin{propertylist}{P}[resume]
\item Property two.\qedhere
\end{propertylist}
%
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

I used `\qedhere` because I can't stand dangling tombstones.

[image]

Comment: You really should look at the  vertical space above the resumed list; it looks larger than the space between the two items in the "how it works" example, and is definitely larger than the comparable space in the "Sufficiency" example.

Comment: @egreg: Why `\proplis` and `\endproplis` instead of `\begin{proplis}` and `\endd(proplis}`? [p.s., I _always_ do use `\qedhere`in my actual documents but omitted it in this MWE. ]

Comment: @barbarabeeton They’re two separate lists; I guess that the OP will have text between them

Comment: @murray `resume` needs to know the *name* of the environment it refers to. But with `\begin{proplis}` there is nothing to resume, because the current environment is named `propertylist`; try both versions.