# How align "tags" on items in an enumitem list?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumitem

How can I get the descriptive "tags" (*symmetry*) and (*the triangle inequality)* to the right of items (M3) and (M4) — which are *not* tags in the usual sense of cross-referencing — in the `propertylist` environment below to be aligned automatically, without my having to insert space manually, as I did here, with `\qquad`, etc.?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{embrac}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{proplis}{enumerate}{1}
\newenvironment{propertylist}[1]{%
  \setlist[proplis,1]{%
  wide,leftmargin=*,label=\upshape(#1\arabic*)}\begin{proplis}%
  \itshape}
  {\end{proplis}}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{propertylist}{M}

\item
$d(x, y) \geq 0$.

\item
$d(x, y) = 0$ if and only if $x = y$.

\item
$d(x, y) = d(y, x)$. \qquad\qquad\qquad\embparen{symmetry}%

\item
$d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z)$. \qquad\,\embparen{the triangle inequality}%

\end{propertylist}

\end{document}
```

[image: left-aligned "tags" to be obtained]

The overall structure of the `propertylist` environment, allowing one argument (here `M`) and underlying `proplist` enumeration needs to be kept, so that I can create similar lists with number prefixes other than M.

For a simpler version of this situation, see [How align "tags" on right of items in a simple enumitem enumeration?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636412/how-align-tags-on-right-of-items-in-a-simple-enumitem-enumeration).

Related: [How use some options for an enumitem list inside a proof environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615263/how-use-some-options-for-an-enumitem-list-inside-a-proof-environment)

Answer (score 1):

Below I provide three options for specifying the alignment based on varying needs/wants:

1. You can set the elements within the `propertylist` that should have tags inside a `l`eft-aligned zero-width (`0pt`) box and follow each item with the same `\hspace` with parameter to have the tags line up. So, each `\item` will have the following standard format:

   ```
   \item \makebox[0pt][l]{<your item>}\hspace{<len>}<your tag>
   ```
2. If you want the tags to line up based some other length criteria like the widest list element, for example, you can use `\hphantom`s instead. Now your tagged items will have the following standard:

   ```
   \item \makebox[0pt][l]{<your item>}\hphantom{<longest item>}<your tag>
   ```
3. If you want to be a bit more free-spirited, you can mark the location on the page (specifically, the `x`-coordinate) via [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module and `\zsaveposx`. It uses a `\label`-`\ref`-like system for memorising the horizontal location, which you can then use to jump to a specific spot on the page.

   I defined user-friendly commands `\newtagpos{<tag>}` to mark a location and `\jumptotagpos{<tag>}` to jump, horizontally, to the correct spot. Note that it'll jump to the correct spot, even if that means jumping backwards and therefore could overwrite content. Also, it assumes you're using a `oneside` document layout or your tags appear on the same page type (recto or verso), since that holds the horizontal positions similar. Under `twoside`, for example, the text blocks are shifted to accommodate for a gutter.

   Since this option uses a `\label`-`\ref`-like setup, changes in any of the horizontal positions of `\newtagpos` or `\jumptotagpos` will require an additional compilation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{embrac}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}

\newlist{proplis}{enumerate}{1}
\newenvironment{propertylist}[1]{%
  \setlist[proplis,1]{%
    wide,leftmargin=*,label=\upshape(#1\arabic*)}
  \begin{proplis}%
    \itshape}
  {\end{proplis}}

\newcommand{\newtagpos}{\zsaveposx}
\newcounter{tagposcnt}
\newcommand{\jumptotagpos}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{tagposcnt}%
  \zsaveposx{tag-\thetagposcnt}%
  \hspace*{\dimexpr\zposx{#1}sp-\zposx{tag-\thetagposcnt}sp}%
}

\begin{document}

Option 1:
\begin{propertylist}{M}
  \item
  $d(x, y) \geq 0$.

  \item
  $d(x, y) = 0$ if and only if $x = y$.

  \item
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$d(x, y) = d(y, x)$.}\hspace{15em}\embparen{symmetry}%

  \item
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z)$.}\hspace{15em}\embparen{the triangle inequality}%
\end{propertylist}

Option 2:
\begin{propertylist}{M}
  \item
  $d(x, y) \geq 0$.

  \item
  $d(x, y) = 0$ if and only if $x = y$.

  \item
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$d(x, y) = d(y, x)$.}\hphantom{$d(x, y) = 0$ if and only if $x = y$.}\embparen{symmetry}%

  \item
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z)$.}\hphantom{$d(x, y) = 0$ if and only if $x = y$.}\embparen{the triangle inequality}%
\end{propertylist}

Option 3:
\begin{propertylist}{M}
  \item
  $d(x, y) \geq 0$.

  \item
  $d(x, y) = 0$ if and only if $x = y$.

  \item
  $d(x, y) = d(y, x)$.\jumptotagpos{ptag}\embparen{symmetry}%

  \item
  $d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z)$.\qquad\newtagpos{ptag}\embparen{the triangle inequality}%
\end{propertylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: These methods obviously work. A simpler solution, though, seems to be to use the `eqparbox` package, as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/636417/13492.

Comment: @murray: True, yet another option. A better choice for `\eqmathbox` would be from [How to place right brace next to table row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412956/5764) - it uses `\mathpalette` to distinguish between the different math styles.