# How align "tags" on right of items in a simple enumitem enumeration?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumitem

How can I get the "tags" (symmetry), (additivity), etc., on the right of the items in the alphabetically enumerated listed below to be aligned on their left, as indicated by the arrows?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{alphenum}
{\begin{enumerate}[label= \sffamily\upshape(\alph*)]}
{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alphenum}

\item
$\langle x, y\rangle = \langle y, x\rangle$ for all $x, y$. (symmetry)

\item
$\langle x + y, z\rangle = \langle x, z\rangle + \langle y, z\rangle$ for all $x, y, z$. (additivity) 

\item
$\langle\lambda x, y\rangle = \lambda \langle x, y\rangle$ for all $\lambda$ and all $x, y$.
(homogeneity)

\end{alphenum}

\end{document}
```

[image: Want to left-align "tags"]

This is a simpler version of the similar question [How align "tags" on items in an enumitem list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636399/how-align-tags-on-items-in-an-enumitem-list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with the `eqparbox` package: I defined an `\eqmathbox` command, with its content in math mode, which uses a tag as an optional argument. All boxes sharing the same tag have the length of the longest of these boxes. Of course, this requires two compilations.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{alphenum}
{\begin{enumerate}[label= \sffamily\upshape(\alph*)]}
{\end{enumerate}}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1][l]{$#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alphenum}

\item
\eqmathbox{\langle x, y\rangle = \langle y, x\rangle \text{ for all } x, y.} (symmetry)

\item
\eqmathbox{\langle x + y, z\rangle = \langle x, z\rangle + \langle y, z\rangle \text{ for all } x, y, z.\qquad} (additivity)

\item
\eqmathbox{\langle\lambda x, y\rangle = \lambda \langle x, y\rangle\text{ for all }\lambda \text{ and all }x, y.}
(homogeneity)
\end{alphenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That does exactly what I want, and without one having to determine explicitly which of the "tags" is the widest. But I do worry about the age of the `eqparbox` package, which has a 2017 date.

Comment: That will need to be modified if, as I think I prefer, the longest "tag" is not necessarily flush right.

Comment: Which tags do you mean? The tags in your question? No tag is flushright with this code.

Comment: quite right: even the widest, "(homogeneity)", is *not* flush right. I couldn't see that from the output you posted, but I can now if I add a `\noindent\hrulefill` after the `alphenum` environment. Now I have to study the docs to see how `eqparbox` determines how much space to leave between the actual math in a given item and the descriptive text tag after it.

Comment: Am I mistaken, or won't this use of `eqparbox` force the same horizontal position of the left-side of the "tags" to be exactly the same for *every* `alphenum` environment in the entire document? Is there some way to have separate determinations of that location for each individual `alphenum` environment?

Comment: @Murray: I chose the `\eqmakebox` on which  this construct is based to be left aligned. But one may also  decide that `[l]` is an optional argument for `\eqmathbox`, and change it  for each item.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by considering `[l]` as an optional argument here. What other values could it take? (Sorry, I'm having considerable trouble penetrating the documentation for he `eqparbox` package.)

Comment: @murray: well, as I thought you wanted the conten left aligned, I incorporated `[l]` in the definition of `\eqmathbox`, but you can use `\NewDocumentCommand \eqmathbox{o m}{…] `, where o is an optional argment and m a  mandatory argument (the content). By default, it will be centred, just as `\makebox` is centred.

Comment: I *do* want left alignment But what does the argument `M` do? Is that fixing a single group for the entire document, so that the same widest element is used in all lists where `\eqmathbox` is used? If so, how do I change things so as to allow different widest elements for different lists?

Comment: `M` is the default value of the tag of the `\eqmakebox`es. If you want to have different widest elements, you only have to use different  tags for the corresponding `eqmakebox`es. Am I clear?

Comment: I think so. I've always seen only single letters for tags.

Comment: @Berbard: Odd, since the `eqparbox` package docs say, at the top of page 4: "<*tag*> can be any valid identifier"!

Comment: The problem is to know what a ‘valid identifier’ is, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc} 
\newenvironment{alphenum}%
   {\begin{enumerate}[label= \sffamily\upshape(\alph*),left=0pt]}%
   {\end{enumerate}}  
\newcommand\RHSbox[1]{\hfill\parbox{\widthof{(homogeneity)}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alphenum}
\item
$\langle x, y\rangle = \langle y, x\rangle$ 
  for all $x$ and $y$. \RHSbox{(symmetry)}

\item
$\langle x + y, z\rangle = \langle x, z\rangle + \langle y, z\rangle$ 
  for all $x$, $y$, and $z$. \RHSbox{(additivity)}

\item
$\langle\lambda x, y\rangle = \lambda \langle x, y\rangle$ 
  for all $\lambda$ and all $x$ and $y$. \RHSbox{(homogeneity)}

\end{alphenum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As it stands, that will require a new `\RHSbox` for each such list! A workaround for that would be to give `\RHSbox` a 2nd argument, namely, the desired widest "tag" for the particular list at hand. In any case, this still requires the manual intervention of determining what is the widest of the tags in a given list.

Comment: @murray - How was I to know -- divine, maybe? -- that there might be more than such list in your document? My divination skills are pretty much worthless. Guess what? This utter lack of usable divination skills has never bothered me so far. Replacing `\newcommand\RHSbox[1]{\hfill\parbox{\widthof{(homogeneity)}}{#1}}` with `\newcommand\RHSbox[2][(homogeneity)]{\hfill\parbox{\widthof{#1}}{#2}}` and asking you to come up with a new "longest word in a list" for each such list in the document is asking rather a lot, isn't it? My abject apologies.

Comment: It's a matter of weighing a per-list maximum (an annoyance), on the one hand, against a per-document maximum, on the other hand, that would be fatal in case of a very wide "tag" then that is pushed very far to the right because the widest math expression on the left is very wide.

Comment: Sorry! When posing a question, it's always a problem of weighing just enough information against too much context.